# Unknown Open Collaboration Service API error (405)

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma, ocs-inventory-ng

The error pops up at the bottom of the window.  I don't see some items that are in the KDE Store, like [Suru Plus 25](https://store.kde.org/p/1245808/) icon pack.  Sometimes, it doesn't recognize that stuff I installed from KDE Store (and sometimes, I can still update  a selected item).

[image: Error at the bottom of the window]

Posted the bug (if it is a bug) in [KDE's bug tracker](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=405584)

Comment: More information: Also posted [on reddit/kubuntu](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kubuntu/comments/b2e7wz/unknown_open_collaboration_service_api_error_405/) with a response that the issue is fixed as described in [bug #391111](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=391111).